# Are privacy zk-roll ups the Ethereum-equivalent of Bitcoin Tumblers?

Tags: bitcoin, privacy, zksnark, tornado-cash, mixers

In Bitcoin, people can move bitcoin privately using **Tumblers** or **Mixers** to obfuscate source of funds, like Tornado Cash.

In Ethereum, is the equivalent of this seems to be **Privacy ZK roll-ups** like Aztec Network's zk.money, which also obfuscate source of funds?

Just trying to ask if Tumblers and Privacy Zk-roll ups are equivalent analogies between the 2 ecosystems, or if actual Tumblers also exist on Ethereum. Wait, doesn't Tornado Cash also tumble Ethereum, not just Bitcoin?

Comment: Bitcoin Tumbers are tracable : first‑in, first‑out.

Answer (score 2):

Tumblers/mixers are not the same as ZK implementations. TornadoCash does not accept Bitcoin so the first bit of your post is wrong. TornadoCash runs on EVM. How can it accept a BTC transaction? It can't unless you use something like WBTC.

I think you should know the difference between a tumbler/mixer does and what ZK does.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: What are the differences then between a mixer like TornadoCash and a privacy zk roll-up like Aztec?

Comment: Transactions made via a mixer remain on-chain, it just mixes the inputs/outputs - e.g you don't get the same coins you sent, sent back to you. ZK roll-ups store transactions off-chain. 

Mixers rely on lots of people using them. The greater the number of inputs into the mixer - the greater the anonymity. Transactions are sequential.

ZK uses validity proofs to confirm the correctness of off-chain state transitions.

Comment: Then move that comment into your answer since that's what the question asks

Comment: No it doesn't - your question did not ask for the differences. It asked if two things were the equivalent. If you have follow up questions, you add it to your post. That's how this works.

Comment: *"your question did not ask for the differences. It asked if two things were the equivalent"*. SMH.

Comment: 